# Find a unique solution for the Decomposition of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ be two known symmetric and positive definite matrices such that they can be decomposed as
$$
\Sigma_1 = A + B_1  \;\;\;\; \Sigma_2 = A+B_2
$$
where A, $B_1$ and $B_2$ are symmetric matrices. 
We want to find the solutions for $A$, $B_1$ and $B_2$ such that this solution is unique.
In particular, by solving these two matrix equations you can have many possible solutions bringing to the same $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, for example

1) $A = a$,  $B_1=b_1$ and $B_2 =b_2 $

2) $A = a/2$, $B_1 = a/2 +b_1$ and $B_2 = a/2 + b_2$.

How can I have a unique solution? My intuition is to impose the constraint that the intersection of the span of $B_1$ and $B_2$ to be empty. Do you have a proof for that or other constraints?

Comment: The only unique solution exists if $B_1 = -B_2$  I think.

Comment: Can you explain or proof why?

Comment: Because then you have two equations with two unknowns, $A$ and $B=B_1=-B_2$.